# jqgrid row background colour change

Tags: asp.net, grid, jqgrid, jqgrid-asp.net

I have a jq grid, and I have to check for a particular value in a column and change the row corresponding to the column (say red).

I can get the row index, but I can't work out how to access that row and change its background.

TIA
Bibhu

Comment: protected void JQGrid1_CellBinding(object sender, JQGridCellBindEventArgs e) { if (e.ColumnIndex == 6) { string value = Convert.ToString(e.CellHtml); if (value == "pending)") { e.CellHtml = String.Format("<div class='redColor'>{0}</span>", e.CellHtml); int rowindex = e.RowIndex; } } } this way i can get the row index, but how to change the background of entire row

Comment: As I see from code, you are using asp.net version of jqGrid, am I right?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
afterInsertRow: function(rowid, aData, rowelem)
     { 
        if (aData.field =='value'){   
            jQuery("#list1").setCell(rowid,'message','',{color:'red'});  
        }  
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as i know there isn't a way to change the cell color from the server-side. However, you can inject onReady javascript into the browser to change the cell colors once done rendering. Here is an example of the javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#myGrid tr:nth-child(1) td:nth-child(2)').addClass("highlight");
});
```

This will change the class of the cell at position 2 (1-based) in row 1 of your grid (Id "myGrid") to "highlight".  If you need the code for injecting javascript from the server-side here is a C# example:

```
this.Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(
    typeof (myPage), 
    "scriptIdentifier", 
    "The JavaScript you want to send to the page", 
    true);
```